# Calculating using $f(x) = kx^2e^{-x}$, ($k>0$)

Tags: calculus, functions

For the function $f(x) = kx^2e^{-x}$, ($k>0$) and a real number $t$, let's call $g(t)$ a smaller value between the distance of a point $(t, f(t))$ on the y=f(x) to x-axis and to y-axis.

What is the biggest value of k that makes $g(t)$ not differentiable at only one point?

My approach is as follow

$g\left( t \right) = t + k{t^2}{e^{ - t}}$ is the sum of distances

$g'\left( t \right) = 1 - k{t^2}{e^{ - t}} + 2kt{e^{ - t}} = 0$ as we need to find the minimum

$g''\left( t \right) =  - 2kt{e^{ - t}} - k{t^2}{e^{ - t}} + 2k{e^{ - t}} - 2kt{e^{ - t}} =  - k{t^2}{e^{ - t}} + 2k{e^{ - t}} - 4kt{e^{ - t}}$ checking the values

How do we approach from here

Comment: Isn't your $g(t)=\min{(t, f(t))}$? What is the connection between $g(t)$ and $D(t)$?

Comment: done correction in the formula

Comment: Your are defining $g(t)$ as the **smaller** of the distances between the point $(t,f(t))$ and the two axes. So how can it be the sum of those two distances?

Comment: In $g''$ factor out the exponential term, which is always positive and then look where the quadratic in $t$, which remains is positive/negative.